# Does "When enter on the battlefield" trigger heroic?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

When a [Satyr Grovedancer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=380492) enters on the battlefield and I choose a creature with heroic to recieve the a +1/+1 counter, does it trigger the heroic? I don't think so because the heroic says explicitly that when a spell targets that creature but I would like to check.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Heroic abilities trigger *whenever you cast a spell that targets this object*. Creature spells (e.g. [Satyr Grovedancer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Satyr%20Grovedancer)) do not target. Satyr Grovedancer has a triggered ability that targets, but abilities aren't spells.

In contrast, [Gossamer Phantasm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gossamer%20Phantasm) has the ability *When Gossamer Phantasm becomes the target of a spell or ability, sacrifice it.* Targeting Gossamer Phantasm with Satyr Grovedancer's triggered ability would trigger Gossamer Phantasm's. (Gossamer Phantasm's will resolve first.)